# What does this code do?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, security

I've been looking at ways to make websites more secure and in particular WordPress site and found a blog post with a few suggestions. Most of them I was already using but found this one with no explanation beyond: "add to .htaccess. stop some injections":

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

I'd be greatful is someone could breakdown what this does and how useful it actually is.

Thanks.